# Create advanced portal website with sections - taxonomy usage?

Tags: customization, taxonomy

I would need your help. Please let me explain my needs. I need to create a portal-based website, and I have some doubts about the right way.

The homepage will contain a few "sections". Each section is dedicated to different sort of users. The users will register to this website and when registering, they have to choose in which section/sections they will register and then they can add posts appearing in these concrete sections. Each section has more subsections.

Let me show you an example - imagine that you are an artist and want to write articles on my website. You are interested in painting and in sculptures. So you register and during the registration you need to apply to these two sections. Then when you are writing an article, you will choose in which section it will appear.

My very raw idea - I have custom post type, which is let's say "article". But it is not important. I will register custom taxonomies, and I think I need one taxonomy for each section. So for painting I can have portrait, pop art, animals.. I don't know. Then when writing this article, I will check the taxonomy I need. Problem is - when I applied to the painting section and sculptures, I must not see the rest of the sections.. So no photography let's say..

So in general - am I able to prepare some WP-based structure for these section, to have custom taxonomy for each section and to filter the displayed taxonomies when creating the "article" depending on the sections the user is registered to? I hope it is clear for you, I am not good at explanations.....

Thanks to everyone for each idea that could show me the way, I don't want complete solutions, just pointing the directions. Thanks!

Comment: If the different sections never interact could you maybe just set up different blogs?

Comment: Mm and can i share users between these blogs? One user can have access to more sections..

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question. Are you just trying to allow certain users to only post in certain categories?

Comment: Basically yes, but there is a little bit more complicated flow.. Users choose which "parent" category they want to post in and they also can post in all subcategories. But I think I will create custom post type for each of the toplevel sections.. I don't think there is any other way easily achieved by wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

If you are OK choosing which categories users can post to check out [restrict categories](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/restrict-categories/). You can assign each user one or multiple categories that they can post to.